# Why zip function cannot be used to read large files simultaneously in python?

Tags: python

I need to process two large files simultaneously, which means that their lines are corresponding to each other, and I need to filter some lines in both files. I'm using the following code:

```
    with open(path1, "r") as fq, \
        open(path2, "r") as ft, \
        open(path3 + ".filter", "w") as wtq, \
        open(path4 + ".filter", "w") as wtt:
    for q, t in zip(fq, ft):
        q, t = q.strip().split(), t.strip().split()
        ...
        wtq.write(" ".join(q) + "\n")
        wtt.write(" ".join(t) + "\n")
```

But the memory usage increase gradually until the program is killed.

When I change it to the following, it went OK:

```
   for q in fq:
        t = ft.readline()
         ...
```

How zip function works and how to read multiple large files simultaneously gracefully?

Comment: `zip()` makes a list in Python2, therefore the whole contents are read in memory, and then traversed by the loop. Try using `izip()` instead

Comment: Import izip from the itertools module.

Comment: Thank You! I previously used python3 and zip to read files simultaneously only with small-size data. Today I got this trouble.

Comment: In Python2, `zip` builds a list and `izip` an iterator. In Python3, `izip` is gone and `zip` builds an iterator (same with `map` and `imap`, `range` and `xrange`).